# Warning: mysqli::__construct(): MYSQLI PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I am not really familiar with `mysqli` that much, and I have to upgrade my script to `mysqli`, please could you help me sort it?

I have this

```
function getConnected($host,$db_user,$db_password,$db) {

       $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $db_user, $$db_password, $db);

       if($mysqli->connect_error) 
         die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());

       return $mysqli;
    }
    $mysqli = getConnected("localhost", "user_name_data456", "password123456", "user_database456");
```

and my query

```
        mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
        mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql2);
        mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql3);
        mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql4);
        mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql5);
```

The queries sql1 - 5 are working fine, it just has some insert things, I know doing more queries on mysql or mysqli isn't recommended, but I am just too tired.

Please help me sort it out. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $db_user, $$db_password, $db);
```

to

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db);
```

removed extra `$` from `db_password` variable

Comment: Oh my god, I feel so stupid.. The no sleep part did its trick. ughhhh, thanks alot everything works fine

Comment: @T.Lowly it's not a no sleep part but no error reporting part. Were you had error reporting properly set, you'd been told by PHP what's wrong

Comment: @YourCommonSense Im not really sure which part of "not really familiar with mysqli" you misunderstood, but Im not hare to take on arguments, thanks for the tip, next time before I am planning on sleeping Ill definitely check out a tutorial that takes probably longer than my eyes can stay open and then just, quickly finish a script, and go to sleep. Anyways thanks, please don't reply.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm sorry I over reacted a bit, just few things annoyed me recently and feel on the edge, anyways, you are right, I should've thought of using error reporting, that's my own stupidity. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Who give me -1. Please tell me my fault. I will correct it

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain Dont know, I upvoted it and gaved it a winning reply, I couldnt do it imedeatly